# How to ensure that sitecore_web_index is up to date on CD server

Tags: indexing, lucene

I run *Lucene* indexes on *Sitecore 8.1*.

I have a custom index that is being generated correctly (on sitecore_web_index) on the CM server, but this change is not reflected on the CD server.

Further details are as follows:

- I added log entries to the index generation process: when I publish relevant items from the Sitecore control panel on the CM server, those entries appear on the Sitecore log and the sitecore_web_index is updated correctly.
- No matter if Smart Publish, Republish or Reindex a tree, the correct values are only updated on the sitecore_web_index of the CM server, never on CD.
- No other index has this problem, everything else seems to be copied just fine on CD.

**Question:**
How can I ensure index consistency between CM and CD servers?

EDIT: this is the entire Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                  <Limit>300</Limit>
                </policy>
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
            <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
            <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share your index configuration? Might be an issue with your update strategy.. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies

Comment: The entire Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config and Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Master.config?

Comment: The web - I understood master is working fine so we don't need that one. Especially the <strategies> and the <locations> part to start with..

Comment: Added in the Question.

Comment: Since you strategy is onPublishEndAsync, it should update the index after each publish job runs. You need to make sure EnableEventQueues is enabled. <setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true">

Comment: Please view the page /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx on your CD and CM servers and make EnableEventQueues is set to true.

Comment: EnableEventQueues is indeed true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a chat on Slack we ruled out a bad config and the EventQueue was enabled.

So another reason for this behavior could be a corrupted index. A rebuild can fix this. Rebuilding on the CD requires the RemoteRebuild strategy though. As a quick fix, you can delete all index files on the CD and copy the files from a working environment (CM) for the same index.

When the new index is in place, test if the index is updating again.

Comment: I believe Sitecore suggests/recommends that if you are running separate CD/CM servers, you should use Solr, not Lucene.

Comment: Thanks Pete - alas, Lucene is what we have and it's not easy to change it now. Also, it worked flawlessly for years... until now.

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi: You should note that if you ever upgrade to a later version (like Sitecore 9) you will no longer be in a supported configuration. Lucene is no longer supported for production or scaled scenarios starting with Sitecore 9.

As Pete Navarra mentions, even on 8.1 it is not recommended: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/using_solr_or_lucene

Comment: Thanks Jay - we are actually planning to upgrade to 9.1 shortly.

"Not supported" means it won't work, or it works but they won't provide official support?

Comment: I'm quite sure I heard that 9.1 wouldn't work with Lucene anymore...When upgrading, you really should move to Solr